# Using SymbolSource Community with Private NuGet Repo

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-server

We are trying to set up SymbolSource community (http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-03-13/Releasing_the_community_edition_of_SymbolSource) to run alongside our private NuGet repo. The SymbolSource server is seemingly working. We can push and list packages. If we use the SymbolSource server as our NuGet server, everything works fine and we can step into the NuGet package while debugging. However, we'd like to be able to use the private NuGet server to download the packages and then use SymbolSource for symbols.

If we use the internal NuGet server to download the package, and the SymbolSource server for symbols (setting `localhost/WinDbg/pdg` in Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols), we are unable to step into the package while debugging. There is no output at all. We think the symbols are on the server because

```
nuget list -Source http://localhost/NuGet/FeedService.mvc
```

Lists the package we are trying to use. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Have you looked at ProGet (http://inedo.com/proget)? It's has symbol/package support, and may a bit easier to configure... (disclaimer: I work for Inedo)